# Old Component being referenced despite using different rendering function

Tags: reactjs

I have a Component that essentially renders a set of other Components based on it's current `stage`. For example, if `stage = 1`, it will use a function like `renderOne`, and so on for other `stage`s. Sometimes, two functions will share similar Components:

```
renderOne(){
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h3>One</h3>

      <Tab
        id="one"
        values={...}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

renderTwo(){
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h3>Two</h3>

      <Tab
        id="two"
        values={...}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

In this case, the version of `Tab` that gets rendered is the first one that is mounted. So if the page starts on `stage = 2` then moves to `stage = 1`, the Component defined by `renderTwo` is rendered even when `renderOne` is called. I noticed this does not happen if for example `renderOne` was instead:

```
renderOne(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>One</h3>

      <Tab
        id="one"
        values={...}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this some behaviour of React that tries to improve performance by reducing rerenders?

React version is 18. Here is an example in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/component-reference-j6l6w4

Comment: Do `stage` changes trigger a rerender ? Are you using `<StrictMode>` ? You will have to show more code so we know how the page is working. Even better if you can provide a fully working example.

Comment: Sure, I will update the post with a codesandbox example

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but `<div className="section"><Renderer /></div>` works as expected (jsx instead of `{renderer()}`)

Answer (score 0):

When you render the same exact structure, react will update their props and not un-mount/mount them.

If you want to force an un-mount/mount you need to provide a different `key`. So adding a key to the outer element that changes will cause it to un-mount the old one and mount the new one.

```
renderOne(){
  return (
    <Fragment key="one">
      <h3>One</h3>

      <Tab
        id="one"
        values={...}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

renderTwo(){
  return (
    <Fragment key="two">
      <h3>Two</h3>

      <Tab
        id="two"
        values={...}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Updated demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/component-reference-forked-s92szt

Comment: Ah OK, that works! Yeah, our actual code for the Tab component has a lot of post processing on the initial props, so just having the props change without mounting is problematic. Perhaps we should rethink that.... Anyway, thank you for your help.